# How to install SOLR on Rackspace Server through SSH?

Tags: solr, ssh, rackspace

Please guide to me that How to install SOLR on Rackspace Server through SSH access?

Awaiting for positive response!

Thanks!

Best Regards,
Pawan Kr Pathak

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your concrete problem? Have you googled and did you follow the documentation you found there ... ?

Comment: Hi Cheff, I did not find any google help. So, please help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

Installing on Rackspace is no different than installing on a host at any other provider.  You just need to read the Solr documentation: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_1/tutorial.html